# How to make my calculation faster? problem appending from txt file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, opencv, append

I have txt file which has

```
x1,y1,z1,w1,desc1
x2,y2,z2,w2,desc2
till
xn,yn,zn,wn,descn
```

x,y,z and w are floats
desc is 61 floats (Not array or list! The drawing in the picture just for illustration)

I need to apply the equation mentioned below in the picture
[image: Need to apply the equation and have the output (u1 and v1 correspondence to desc1)]

My code is

```
for i in range(len(Xsnew)):
            #Xsnew is all the x's in the txt file
            x_features = Xsnew[i]
            y_features = Ysnew[i]
            z_features = Zsnew[i]
            #print("x_features", x_features)
            # Feature coordinates is the 3x1 matrix x1 y1 z1 in the picture
            feature_coordinates = np.array([[x_features],[y_features],[z_features],[1]], dtype=float)
            # P in the picture is the projection matrix 
            position_of_features = np.dot(projection_matrix, feature_coordinates)
            u, v, w = position_of_features[0], position_of_features[1], position_of_features[2]
            u_normalized = u / w
            v_normalized = v / w
            #print("U normalized is {} and V normalized is {}". format(u_normalized,v_normalized))
            virtual_camera_desc = desc_features[i]
            #print("virtual_camera_desc", virtual_camera_desc)

            #print(" u = {} and v = {} and X_features = {} and desc = {}". format(u_normalized,v_normalized,x_features,virtual_camera_desc))
            if 0 < u_normalized < image_height and 0 < v_normalized < image_width:
                #print(len(desc), len(virtual_camera_desc))
                #print("I SEE FEATURES")
                bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck= True)
                matches = bf.match(desc, virtual_camera_desc)
```

This worked quite fine, But it is so slow.
I need want faster algorithm was thinking somehow to do "live". But not sure, how to start? Any advice please?

Thanks:)

Comment: @Evorage Thank you for the advice. But still I believe Python can make such process. It is matter of algorithmic issue more than language issue. For sure C++ would be faster. But this script is a small part of big project written in Python and changing to another language is not an option in the mean time. Thanks a lot:)

Comment: Why don't vectorize the whole thing? To begin with, i think you can directly read off the data from the file since it's not too big and use numpy for the calculation? Avoiding the loop in Py; Throwing it to numpy will definitely boost your speed; Or try wrapping it up with numba.jit;

Comment: @Aditya I agree with you, any advice/code how to start:)) Seems for me challenging, Sorry I am still beginner!